# Strange icon behavior

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm having a problem with a new App that I'm developing. I have a App with no main icon/logo for the application running, the problem is that everytime I run the App on the device an icon from another App appears on my application, tests that i have made:

- I made sure my app certificate was unique and it is.
- I checked the app folder for icon images and found nothing.
- I cleaned xcode and restarded my mac.

Comment: Have you checked your Info.plist file ?

Comment: may be you have same bundle identifier so it over right the application. change bundle Identifier and check

Comment: delete your app from device. Restart your device and install your app again.

Comment: what about the device? did you remove the application from the device?

Comment: Is there any images on resource folder in the name of icon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could happen in the case of not-unique `bundle identifier`. Your Bundle ID should follow this format:

```
com.companyname.appname
```